# istio VirtualService is not working for my configuration

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a digitalocean kubernetes cluster with istio installed on it. I get 404 not found error on accessing the apis on the postman application. Here's my vs-gateway yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ut-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: utbuild1
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - ut-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /v3/api/products/search
    rewrite:
      uri: /api/products/search # or /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: utbuild1 # pods/service created using istio-k8s-single-deployment.yaml (this service has 3 pods)
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /v4admin/api
    route:
    - destination:
        host: utbuild1-admin # pod/service created using istio-k8s-single-deployment.yaml
```

Comment: What apiVersion of Gateway abstraction?

Comment: @Vielen Danke, I edited the yaml code.